# Does a character have to use Change the Game to attack with an object in the environment?

Tags: city-of-mist

Say a character is sitting at a bar and a fight breaks out, and they want to use the stool they were sitting on to attack. Can they just use the *stool-1* as a +1 tag, or must they use **Change the Game** before it counts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## "He's got a sword!" "You *idiots*! We've all got swords!"

> **CREATING STORY TAGS**
>
> Players can create story tags using the *Change the Game* move (or any move or game option that generates Juice, see page 232).
>
> [...] The MC can create story tags whenever she deems it appropriate, but is advised to use them sparingly; one or two story tags per scene should be enough to make things interesting.
>
> -- *City of Mist Player's Guide*, p.212

When something exists as a story tag, that means it's special and meaningful. Anything you get out of *Change the Game* is a consequence of applying your mythologos to the situation at hand. Anything the MC drops into the scene is there to be a significant component of the scene.

So, if you snatch up *a bar stool* as a story tag, perhaps as the result of ticking Broad Training and saying how sensei taught you to look for weapons everywhere, what that means is probably best translated as "I have a bar stool *and you don't*."

On the other hand, if you don't take a chance to *Change the Game* or make use of other character features, if picking up a bar stool is just something anyone could do, what's stopping just anyone from doing it, in what I can only assume is a knock-down drag-out fight suddenly kicking off in a diner? And then everybody's got a bar stool, so your bar stool isn't special and never was.

Answer (score 1):

Talk to your MC!

If it's already in the narrative (like the stool you're sitting on, I suppose) then it makes sense that it could be used as a story-tag.  It becomes a story-tag because it's become *important* to the story, if only for that one action against one target (Player's Guide 182).   *With* a *Change-the-Game* roll, it might become usable throughout the entire fight (on a 10+).

If you don't explicitly discuss this with the MC, the using the stool is just narrative color--your description of what happened and how it happened, without any mechanical benefit.